# Hold file handle open, or reopen as needed?

Tags: java

I have a TCP server that handles a specific binary protocol.  Some requests include a large amount of data that is to be written to a file.  The server uses an NIO framework (netty), and has logic in it to deal with messages that have been broken up into multiple frames.

When an individual frame comes in, if the data in that frame is to be written to a file, then I open the file and write the data.  Even if the stream has not finished and I expect another frame with data to be appended to the same file, I currently close the file until I receive the next frame, at which point I reopen it and append the additional data.

I chose this method since it seemed the safest way to avoid leaving open file handles around and through some mistake not closing them, however, I am concerned that this will have negative performance implications.  Is it better (or best practices in this case) to leave the filehandles open (so keep a reference to an open FileOuputStream or Channel)?  Are there resource limit concerns with the number of open file handles?

Comment: What kind of volume (of simultaneously open files) are you considering? And how often are you receiving the frames ­— more or less streaming/realtime? Or with long delays? The rlimits in play tend to be in the hundreds (or thousands) in that respect. And the time taken to open/close the files versus the delay between frames might be a consideration.

Comment: All of those are good points @BRPocock: with most any question of this sort, the real thing to consider is the workload.

Comment: @BRPocock volume is hopefully ever increasing, so I am just trying to find the sweet spot that would offer the best scalability.  Frames are streaming / realtime (the frames in question are just the individual TCP packets).  I'm trying to balance what I think is the safest and most scalable (closing the files) with what is likely the best performing (keeping them open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guarded answer:

- create factory class that handles:

  - returning an open filehandle from a pool, if the given file is still open;
  - closing the eldest (least-recently-used) filehandle, if none are available
    (some tunable upper limit that seems reasonable for your system)
  - fires off a timer on a relatively long duration (30s? a minute?) to close filehandles
    that haven't been used for some time

Something like

```
    /* initialize once */
    FilePool.setLimit (maxFiles);

    /* called often */
    FilePool.getFile(ident);
    FilePool.closeFile(handle);

    /* protected/internal/… */
    boolean FilePool.reachedLimit ();
    FilePool.closeLeastRecentlyUsed (number);
    OnTimer → FilePool.closeIdleFiles (duration);
```

Of course, this only makes sense to the extent that the file open/closing is actually wasting any time.

If you can load-test your existing system and try to profile the time it takes with both
mechanisms, of course, you'd have a better handle on your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I will do, with some minor modifications (or maybe just different naming).  I will make it a non static pool object that returns an OutputStream based on a File key (probably some trouble here with matching File objects that I will ignore..).  It can then either return the cached Stream or a newly opened stream as you essentially indicate, along with the other pool management functions.

Answer (score 3):

It takes 10s to 100s of milliseconds to establish a TCP connection handshake etc, so ideally you won't do it *very* often.  Looking at your explanation, I'd definitely keep the connection open, because your effective bandwidth will be **really** limited if you keep creating a new connection.

Remember that the connection will get closed at shutdown anyway, and will be shutdown at gc time if the object leaves a defined scope.  See if you can't put the connection in a scope to take advantage of that.

**Update**

Just saw the comment that you mean the disk.  The same argument applies, though, although less so because opening a file should take, generally, only a few milliseconds -- probably still in the order of 10 millisec, though.

Comment: it's the disk file he's re-opening, not the TCP stream.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, I think it's better to leave the file handle open.

I've `straced` no end of programs that transfer files over a socket over the years, and I've never yet seen one that repeatedly closed and opened the destination file.

Furthermore, I would probably write the incoming stream to a *temporary* file name, and only rename it to the correct file name on completion.

Comment: Were those programs servers dealing with multiple connections or just single connection / low volume?